# Context.Site.Name changes to wrong site when using AJAX call

Tags: multisite, controller

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1, and a multisite setup.

I have a custom controller rendering that I view from a page in Site2, my controller had 2 methods: an Index() method that returns the view, and a Submit() method that does something else (called by ajax)

What happens is, inside my Index method, Sitecore.Context.Site.Name returns "Site2" correctly, however when I debug inside my Submit() method, Sitecore.Context.Site.Name returns "Site1" for some bizarre reason!

I have tried setting a dummy variable with a value and checking what happens inside each of Index() and Submit(), I tried this code:

```
    public string x = "x";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        x = "y";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Submit(exampleModel ex)
    {
       ...
    }
```

It turns out, as soon as my breakpoint inside Submit() is hit, "x" is reset back to its original value, I think Sitecore.Context.Site is being reset as well, I have no idea why this is happening though.

I need to read the Context.Site.Name correctly, does anyone know why this happens or what I did to cause the reset?

Comment: How do you configure the callback url?

Comment: @MarkCassidy I used an ajax call whose url parameter is "http://mySite/MyController/Submit" and I send my data in it as formData

Comment: a dummy variable is useless, for each request new instance of controller is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore does not resolve the `Sitecore.Context` properly in case of the `HttpPost` through AJAX requests. I would suggest to add the `siteName` as a parameter to your Action as part of the `ExampleModel` and pass this data in the AJAX request, example code below, then you can fetch the needed site by the name.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new ExampleModel 
    {
        SiteName = Sitecore.Context.Site.Name
        /* add other fields this view model if needed */
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public string Submit(ExampleModel ex)
{
   var matchedSite = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList().First(site => site.Name == ex.SiteName);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing a similar solution, I thought I was doing something wrong and that's why Sitecore.Context was incorrect, thanks for the answer :)